# What does "can be said to do / to be" something mean?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, vocabulary

The various modern revolutions in physics, in psychology, in politics, even in literary style, have not escaped his intelligent notice, but they can scarcely be said to have influenced him deeply.

[(Source)](http://gre.kaomanfen.com/question/a3f68h-3)

Could you please explain the following?

They can scarcely be said to have influenced him deeply.

Or, I can not understand such a structure like the following:

In contrast, prices set by a central planner are necessarily arbitrary, since there is no standard against which **they can be said to be** correct or incorrect. d'oh!

Comment: Note that all of these sentences are negative (_scarcely_ is a [negative trigger]()). _Be said to VP_ is not an NPI, but it is most comfortable there; without a negative it's just empty syllables. _He is said to have influenced her deeply_ just means _They say he influenced her deeply_, but requires a whole lot more parsing to get there.

Answer (score 3):

If something *can be said to be* X, it means that it would be possible (or better, accurate or reasonable) to *say* that *something is X*.

Look at the following lines, meaning (very roughly!) the same thing:

> They can scarcely be said to have influenced him deeply.
> It can scarcely be said that they have influenced him deeply.
> It would be wrong to say that they influenced him deeply.
> They did not influence him deeply.

For your last sentence, a similar exercise:

> There is no standard against which they can be said to be correct or incorrect.
> There is no standard we can use to say that they are correct or incorrect
> There is no standard that defines them as correct or incorrect

Comment: More strictly, it is used when it is **accurate** or perhaps  **reasonable** to say that something is X. Foxes have been said by some people to enjoy being hunted, but I'd not accept 'Foxes can be said to enjoy being hunted.'

Comment: Thank you all so much. However, why at my original sentence is used they instead of he,she or it? they can scarcely be said to have influenced him

Comment: @nima_persian: _They_ refers to _The various modern revolutions_ in your original sentence, and to _prices_ in your second. In both cases, it's plural, so no _he_, _she_ or _it_.